# Is there a need to use HTML entities when using Unicode?

Tags: html, unicode, html-entities

I am building a website for a German client, so the text on the website will regularly contain characters like:

- ä
- ö
- ü
- ß

Is it necessary for to convert all those characters to their HTML Entities while the website uses UTF-8 character encoding everywhere?

Or maybe there's no relation between the two areas?

When (if at all) should I convert those to their HTML Entities, then?

Comment: I would personally NOT convert to entities when using UTF8 (and only use UTF8 anyway on a multilingual site) We never do and we have a trilingual interface but can show any language in the text. Come to think of it, there is no longer any real relation. ISO-8859-1 missed some chars so UTF8 is a huge improvement

Comment: ISO-8859-1 missed some chars? Funny way to say it. It missed like 100,000 chars xD

Comment: No need to convert. And, there is no 'unicode encoding'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert to HTML entity or character references when:

a. you are stuck with some editor or processing component that doesn't support Unicode properly;

b. you have manually-edited markup with confusable characters. For example, if you have a non-breaking-space that is important to lay out correctly, you might want to write it as `&nbsp;` or `&#x00A0;` so that it's obvious and doesn't get replaced with a normal space when someone edits the file.

Other than that, no, just go with the raw versions.

Comment: c. You’re forced to due to syntactical requirements.